# Variable number of locks based on parameters

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock

I am trying to implement a two-phase deadlock prevention algorithm in Java. The requirements are basically:

1. In order to make this somewhat easier to eliminate pre-emption, an external text file will contain number of processes and resources in the following format:

```
<line1> number_of_processes
<line2> number_of_resources
<line3> resources_requested_by_process_1
...
<line4> resources_requested_by_process_n
```

For example with 5 processes and 3 resources, it would look like:

```
5
3
1 2
2 3
1
2
1 3
```

2. Each process, when requesting a resource goes through 2 phases. First, it requests a lock on the resource. If granted, it proceeds and then unlocks it before exiting. Otherwise, it releases all its previously held locks and restarts its request from the beginning. I have decided to use Java's ReentrantLock in order to do this locking mechanism.
   So, I am thinking of having a Resource class with a ReentrantLock object.

```
class Resource
{
        private int i;
        private ReentrantLock theLock;

        public Resource(int value) {
            i = value; // this is basically the resource id
            theLock = new ReentrantLock();
        }

        public void use() {
            theLock.lock();
            // do something
            theLock.unlock();
        }
}
```

And each process is going to be a thread. What I want to know is if it's possible to do a variable number of locks based on the input text file. So, if a process needs to request locks for resources 1 and 2, first it will trylock resource 1 and proceed with 2. But some processes will only request 1 and some might request 3. How do I make a method that follows a variable number of lock procedures like so:

```
trylock_for_resource_1
      trylock_for_resource_2
       ...
        trylock_for_resource_n
        ...
        release_lock_for_resource_n
      ...
release_lock_for_resource1
```

I would appreciate any help on this matter. Or if you have a better idea about how I can implement a two phase resource lock algorithm in Java, I would love to read it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to coordinate the locks, so you'd want to have something like this, where the maps and lists are immutable (e.g., Guava `ImmutableList` or `unmodifiableList`):

```
class MapBasedLockingPolicy implements LockingPolicy {
  final Map<String, List<Lock>> locksByResourceName;

  @Override
  List<Lock> locksForResource(String resourceName) {
    return locksByResourceName.get(resourceName);
  }
}
```

Then in your implementation, you'll want to consecutively acquire and release the locks. You can do this iteratively, but the recursive version is a little simpler and probably won't be a problem if you don't have a ton of locks:

```
class LockingUtils {
  <V> static V attemptWithLock(List<Lock> locks, Callable<V> action) {
    if (locks.isEmpty()) {
      return action.call();
    }

    Lock thisLock = locks.get(0);

    if (thisLock.tryLock()) {
      // we hold the lock
      try {
        return attemptWithLock(locks.subList(1, locks.size()), action);
      } finally {
        thisLock.unlock();
      }
    }
    else {
      // return null or throw to indicate locking failure, however you like
    }
  }
}
```

If using Vavr is an option, using `locks.head()`, `locks.tail()`, and a `Try` result might make life a bit simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am having a hard time understanding your MapBasedLockingPolicy class. I am going to attempt to explain what I think it is doing. I am guessing the String in locksByResourceName is the name of resource and the List<Lock> is the list of processes requesting lock on it. If it's not too much of a trouble for you, could you explain your classes in a little more detail. I apologize if my questions are too basic. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand what you mean by V? Are those generics? If so, how do they work in this context?

Comment: @Khatevate `locksByResourceName` is exactly what the name says: the record of the locks to use based on the name of some resource. The `List<Lock>` is the list _of the locks_ that need to be acquired. `V` is a generic, and the `attemptWithLock` takes a list of locks to obtain and your code, written as a lambda, to execute once it has obtained all of those locks. A problem with your original example is that your wrapper `use` method has no way of running something _between_ lock and unlock, and once you introduce the need for multiples, you may as well just use the `Lock` object directly.